# QTLocation: RouteModel Update Error Undefined

Tags: qt, qml, openstreetmap

I am using QT 5.6.0 with Qtcreator 3.6.1 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bits.
I am trying to Find a route from openstreetMap so I have a RouteModel and a RouteQuery.
I added waypoints to the Routequery, change the travelModes to RouteQuery.CarTravel and the routeOptimizations to RouteQuery.fastestRoute.
And then, I dit routeModel.update().

My problem is that the status change (onStatusChanged) to undefined error. First the status is ModelRoute.loading and then the status goes to RouteModel.Error. When I print the errorString, it is written as undefined.

So how can I correct the problem ? Is there a way to obtain more information about the error ?

If I look on the application output, I can see 2 warnings but I am not sure it is the cause :
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method

Do you think it could be the cause of the error ? If Yes, how to correct it ?

I used an example from QT (mapviewer) and I have the same problem with it.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

openstreetmap routing in 5.6.0 is broken, due to OSRM.org having switched off their demo server based on the OSRMv4 protocol.

If you plan to use that software (5.6.0, osm plugin for routing), your only option is to find another open OSRMv4 server (or run your own), and set the plugin with a plugin parameter that specifies the URL of this server instead of using the hardcoded one.